# BigQuery Asynchronus Query Job garbles the Query String

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-client

i'm using the Ruby Google API Client to call BigQuery.  The Query works just fine if I call it synchronously via bq.jobs.query.

Here's the job:  job_sQUillv1JOSPg7XdJa7k8JTexPc

Here's the actual query:

```
    select uid,group_concat(event) as path from
    (select uid, event,t from 
    (select properties.distinct_id  as uid, event , properties.time  as t, t1.ev as ev, t1.time as originalTime from 
    [ziptrips.ziptrips_events ] 
    join 
    ( select properties.distinct_id  as user, properties.time  as time, event  as ev from 
    [ziptrips.ziptrips_events ] where properties.time  > 1385856000  and properties.time  < 1388534399  and event  = 'Home Page Loaded'  
    group by user,time,ev) as t1 
    on t1.user = properties.distinct_id  
    where properties.time  < t1.time) 
    group by uid,event ,t 
    order by t desc) 
    group by uid
```

However when I do the same call asynchronously via bq.jobs.insert, the query string gets garbled (It has a whole bunch of \n and \u003e etc). And the job fails.

```
    select uid,group_concat(event) as path from\n        (select uid, event,t from \n        (select properties.distinct_id  as uid, event , properties.time  as t, t1.ev as ev, t1.time as originalTime from \n        [ziptrips.ziptrips_events ] \n        join \n        ( select properties.distinct_id  as user, properties.time  as time, event  as ev from \n        [ziptrips.ziptrips_events ] where properties.time  \u003e 1385856000  and properties.time  \u003c 1388534399  and event  = 'Home Page Loaded'  \n        group by user,time,ev) as t1 \n        on t1.user = properties.distinct_id  \n        where properties.time  \u003c t1.time) \n        group by uid,event ,t \n        order by t desc) \n        group by uid
```

Here's the code:

```
        client,bq = initialize()
         config = {
        'query' => {
            'query' => query
            }
        }

result = client.execute(:api_method =>  bq.jobs.insert,  
        :parameters => {'projectId' => 'onefold-1'},
        :body_object => {
                    "configuration" => config,
                    "kid" => "bigquery#queryRequest",
                    "query" => query,
                    "maxResults" => 1000,
                    "defaultDataset" => {
                        "datasetId" => "#{dataset_id}",
                        "projectId" => 'onefold-1'
                    },
                    "timeoMs" => 3000,
                    "dryRun" => false,
                    "preserveNulls" => false,
                    "useQueryCache" => true,
                    "miCompletionRatio" => 1.0
                }
        )
```

I believe it has something to do with encoding etc. Can't put my finger on whether and where to specify the encoding. Appreciate any pointers or suggestions.

Thanks,
Navneet

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this was a non-issue. There was a different error happening at the same time and I linked that error to this.
It works!